# Bash scripting if loop

Tags: linux, scripting

```
User=0
echo "Please select av ma ji im pr"
echo -n "First 2 initial of your Name eg: [av ma ji im pr]? "
read User
if [ $User = av ]
        then
                echo `$User`
elfi [ $User = ma ]
        then     # --> This line giving problem "syntax error near unexpected token `then'"
                echo `$User`
elfi [ $User = pr ]
        then
                echo `$User`
else
echo "ur name dsoes not exist"
fi
```

Comment: What language is that? Are you sure `elfi` should not be spelled `elif`?

Comment: Sorry typoo error it is elif

Comment: but still not woking Error in Line # 9

Comment: What error? What language?

Comment: after correction, Still facing same problem

Comment: Sorry friends i am new to scripting i must be irritating you all

Comment: my problem is still not solved

Comment: the above script is working fine now

Comment: but what i want is av ma pr are ENV Variable av=123 ma=234 pr=345

Comment: when i do echo $User the content should appear Like this echo $User

Comment: C an any body solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo with `elif` statements.
Also backticks are not needed in the echo statements. Which will otherwise lead to excute the it as command which is not what you wanted.

```
User=0
echo "Please select av ma ji im pr"    
echo -n "First 2 initial of your Name eg: [av ma ji im pr]? "
read User
if [ $User = av ]
    then
            echo $User
elif [ $User = ma ]
    then
            echo $User
elif [ $User = pr ]
    then
            echo $User
else
echo "ur name dsoes not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to format your question a little bit better next time.

Your error comes because of your "else if" command.

Its not elfi,  its   **elif**

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.
The first is `elfi` should be `elif`.

The second is the backticks around `$user`. They should be removed. Double quotes around the variables should be used in case the variable contains spaces.

```
User=0
echo "Please select av ma ji im pr"
echo -n "First 2 initial of your Name eg: [av ma ji im pr]? "
read User
if [ "$User" = av ]
        then
                echo "$User"
elif [ "$User" = ma ]
        then
                echo $User
elif [ "$User" = pr ]
        then
                echo "$User"
else
echo "ur name dsoes not exist"
fi
```